# KeyError when applying a function to all rows in a data frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, keyerror

I have defined a function as below:

```
def song_words(row):
    # Extracts the song name from the row
    song_name_raw = row['Song'][0]
    # Extracts the song's points from the row
    song_points = row['Points'][0]
```

.
.
.

The function basically associates a word in a song and the number of points for it, given in a tuple.
The output looks like below:
[('Net', 31), ('als', 31), ('toen', 31)]

The above function is only applied to a single row, i.e.  row['Song'][0] and row['Points'][0]

How can I apply the song_words() function to all rows in my dataframe for the two relevant columns (Song, Points)?

I have tried the following ways, but it doesn't work.

```
 data.groupby('Song').apply(song_words)
 data.apply(song_words)
```

any advice appreciated :)

Comment: Without having at least a little part of your dataframe, it would be kinda impossible to guess what's going on. Maybe there is no need to use the `groupby` function or maybe you can do it in a much more efficient way.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to apply to rows, you need to write:

```py
data.apply(song_words, axis=1)
```

Otherwise, `apply` applies the function to a column at a time.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are looking for.

```
def song_words(row):
    # extract song name
    print(row['songs'])
    # extract song points
    print(row['points'])

data = {'songs': ['s1', 's2'], 'points': [10, 9]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df

df.apply(song_words, axis=1)
```